# Why would RDP only work while pinging the machine?

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop, ping

I've got a Windows 7 machine that I can successfully ping at any point.  However I can only connect to it via RDP while also pinging it - if it isn't being pinged, the RDP connection will time out.

I'm trying to RDP via machine name because it uses DHCP so the actual IP varies.

Any suggestions on why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: So when you're pinging are you using the machine name or the IP?

Comment: Machine name...

Comment: I have the reverse problem. Running a continuous ping, packets are timing out, until I try to initiate an RDP connection, at which point the pings immediately start going through, until I cancel the RDP auth dialog, and then the pings immediately stop again!